# Change custom post type slug in functions file

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, slug

In WordPress you can change the Custom Post Type slug easily from the dashboard post shown in the image below, but how can I change it via the back-end for all my CPT's?

[image]

I know I can use the rewrite argument, but that seems to only change the custom post type title.

How can I code a function to change to this:

- sitename/projects/project

instead of

- sitename/projects/slug-of-post

Answer (score 1):

Do I get it right, that you want to change the permalink base?

Custom Post Types are registered through:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/
`register_post_type`

This function has the `rewrite` parameter. The sub parameter `slug` might be what you are searching for.

You can alter the parameters of registered post types with the filter `register_post_type_args`
see here for more information about it:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/230313/179522

Don't forget to flush your permalink rules after doing changes.
Here is how: https://wpastra.com/docs/how-to-refresh-wordpress-permalinks/

Comment: Yes, so I would want to modify the custom post type 'slug-of-post', as for example, 'sitename/projects/slug-of-post'

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at the following plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/ .

It has worked for me, and if would like to write your own functions instead of using a plugin, you could take a look at how the plugin's authors do it.

Thanks!

Comment: I dont want to use plugins